# Key Difference between Active IR image and depth image in Kinect V2

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, depth, infrared

I just have a confusion in understanding the difference between the Active IR image and depth Image of Kinect v2. Can anyone tell me the what special features Active IR image have as compare to depth image?

Answer (score 9):

In the depth image, the value of a pixels relates to the distance from the camera as measured by time-of-flight. For the active infrared image, the value of a pixel is determined by the amount of infrared light reflected back to the camera.

Sidenote:
I think there is only one sensor that does both these. The Kinect uses the reflected IR to calculate time of flight but then also makes it available as an IR image.

Comment: Your hypothesis of using a single depth sensor to get both IR image and depth map seems to be very interesting and plausible to me. However I cannot find any official source where this is confirmed. Do you have some references useful to this end?

Comment: @VitoShadow Technical documents from Microsoft for the Kinect are very rare. The most "official" evidence that I have come across is this teardown of the sensor: https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Xbox+One+Kinect+Teardown/19725